# In bash, check if the file size is changing, execute command if not

Tags: bash

I want to check the file size (in bash on Debian) and if it's not increasing, perform a command. My sh script looks like that:

```
FirstSize=$(du -s /media/USB/km)
echo $FirstSize
sleep 5
SecondSize=$(du -s /media/USB/km)
echo $SecondSize
if [ "$FirstSize" -eq "$SecondSize" ]
then
    echo "size is the same"
    mount -a
    sleep 15
    pkill openRTSP
else
   echo "size is changing"
fi
```

The output I receive is:

```
 135436688 /media/USB/km
    135437444 /media/USB/km
    ./size.sh: 8: [: Illegal number: 135436688 /media/USB/km
    size is changing
```

Could you suggest me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking bash to compare "135436688 /media/USB/km" as a number. You only want the first part of the output from `du`. Try using the `cut` command to do something like this:

```
FirstSize=$(du -s /media/USB/km | cut -f 1)
```

(I'm on cygwin, not Debian so I can't be 100% sure that's exactly what will work for you, but should get you going in the right direction.)

Comment: Btw. what if I wish to check if two strings are the same?

Comment: Bash compares strings with either `=` or `==`. Unfortunately it's more complicated than it should be, as you also have to consider the difference between 'single bracket test' and 'double bracket test'. There are some details here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: Briefly, I think `if [[ "$FirstSize" == "$SecondSize" ]]` would work  to compare strings in your case. Double bracket test is supposedly newer and better than single bracket, but subtle differences like this are why I write most of my scripts in Perl or Python.